# Do reviewers read what they review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

On [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431825/generating-a-md5-checksum-of-a-file/3431835#3431835) I fixed a broken code example. I changed ...

```
[(fname, hashfile(open(fname, 'rb'), hashlib.md5()) for fname in fnamelst]
```

... to ...

```
[(fname, hashfile(open(fname, 'rb'), hashlib.md5())) for fname in fnamelst]
```

... in two places. I added a missing closing bracket.

And because edits need to change at least six chars i also changed some variable names. I dont care about them.

My fix was rejected two times:

[First fix](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5966773): rejected by three reviewers. Ok, these Brackets can be overlooked.

[Second Fix](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5985738): This Time i used big letters in my edit-comment: "PLEASE CHECK THE BRACKETS I ADDED!". It did not help. **One** out of four reviewers approved - [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/399346/rob) - three other dudes rejected it.

So here is my question:

**Do Stackoverflow reviewers actually read what they review or do they just click random buttons?**

Thanks to [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/399346/rob) for carefully reading and approving my fix. You are awesome.

Comment: We don't expect reviewers to be experts in all languages, and suggested edits are not the best avenue to make this change. Best to just leave a comment pointing out the error.

Comment: I removed your 'shaming'; please don't do that. There is never a need to convict people before they have been found guilty, and I disagree that the reviewers did anything wrong here. You attempted to put people doing honest reviews on the scaffold without trial.

Comment: I've made *just* the parentheses edits now. Better to wait until you have 2k+ reputation before attempting such edits, rather than invent different variable names *just* to get around the minimum character limits.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters can you also remove the two incorrect "rejected" from my history?

Comment: No, I cannot. Unless you continue to make edits that are going to be rejected, those edits in your history make no difference, really. And they would only count against you until they are 30 days old in any case.

Comment: Perhaps the fact that 6/7 reviewers rejected your edit is a sign that *you* were wrong, not the reviewers.

Comment: I am objectively right. The six rejects are wrong. Thats all to say about it. Just because the majority thinks that False is True, False does not become True. Embarrassing that i have to point out this on a website related to coding

Comment: I'm not suggesting that adding the missing parenthesis was incorrect. You were absolutely right to add that, and it was in fact an impressive catch. What I'm suggesting is that your initial approach to the edit was incorrect: changing variable names without a compelling reason to do so is definitely grounds for edit rejection, and meeting the minimum character count in an edit is not a good enough reason. As suggested by Andrew's answer, you could leave a comment instead. Your added parenthesis is right; your overall edit is not so black-and-white.

Answer (score 18):

You should not be making unnecessary changes just to hit the minimum-edit-size threshold. If you don't have enough legitimate changes to hit the threshold, leave a comment so someone with full editing privileges can do it.

Comment: This is so good to know, because I've been hit before by the "oh, I'd love to fix that one character typo ..."